# C/C++ How to hand over a const function pointer or a simple pointer in one function call

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants

I have a function (func1) that gets as a parameter a **const pointer**.
The value of this pointer is used for a second function (func2).
Depending on a boolean I want to modify this value before handing it to func2 or not. If I have to modify it I allocate new memory to store the modified version of it. Because in reality the const int pointer is a big array, I don't want to copy it.
I tried to solve it that way:

```
void func1(const int* value, bool change)
{
  int* valueToUse;

  if(change)
  {
     int changedValue = (*value)++;
     valueToUse = &changedValue;
  }
  else
  {
     valueToUse = value;  // <= here the Error occurs
  }

  func2(valueToUse);
}

void func2(const int* foo)
{
  // ...
}
```

But if I do it this way, I get an error because I assign a const pointer to a simple pointer:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const int* to int*'

Is there any easy way to solve this?

I can imagine a solution with two extra functions for each case or a version that calls func2 at two points. But because this presented code is only a very simplified version of my real code, I'm wandering if there is an easier solution to that.

Best would be a solution that works for C and C++.

Thanks guys in advance!

Comment: If you want the function to be able to modify the memory that the pointer argument points to, remove the `const`.

Comment: Maybe you can use another copy which only has the modified values and rest of the values as some sentinel. Now you can pass both the arrays to your other function. It will first look at array2. If it is sentinel, it can take from the main array, if is not sentinel, it will take from the copy array.

Comment: If a sentinel value is not available use a third array of Booleans to tell where to pick the value from. true = value from array2, false = value from array1 (the const one).

Comment: Presumably, your `func2` is expecting a pointer to a single `int` and not a pointer to the first element of an array of `int`. Otherwise it would break horribly.

Comment: Why can't you just declare `valueToUse` as a `const int *` in the above code?

Comment: Since `value` points to a `const int`, aren't you getting an error for this: `int changedValue = (*value)++;`?

Comment: `valueToUse = &changedValue;` you have dangling pointer once out of the scope currently...

Comment: I really wanted a cat so I went to the pet store where they had lots of cats. I decided to buy a dog, even though I don't want one, I wanted a cat all along. So now when I am home, I wonder how to turn the dog into a cat. Going back to the store and returning the dog and instead get the cat that I actually wanted isn't an option, because it would be too easy. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works?

```
void func1(const int* value, bool change)
{
    const int* valueToUse;
    int changedValue;

    if(change)
    {
        changedValue = (*value) + 1;
        valueToUse = &changedValue;
    }
    else
    {
        valueToUse = value;
    }

    func2(valueToUse);
}
```

A `const int*` is a pointer to `const int`, which is not a `const` pointer to `int`. Therefore the pointer itself is free to change.

Also, incrementing `(*value)` is an error because `*value` is a `const int`.

Comment: While I think my solution is simpler and I would probably use that, yours is closer to what the OP asked and doesn't need "the clarification"

Comment: Certainly true, I do prefer the code in your answer much much much more if no restrictions are present

Answer (score 2):

In func1, you can make 2 calls to func2, this way there is no copy when not needed and the original value is never changed:

```
void func1(const int* value, bool change)
{
  if(change)
  {
     int changedValue = *value+1;
     func2(&changedValue);
  }
  else
  {
     func2(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: OP actually explicitly said he does not want two function calls though

Comment: No, he said two extra functions, not two function calls.

Comment: " ...that calls func2 at two points." Am I really reading this wrong? Seriously I'm super not confident today, I've made a billion mistakes already.

Comment: Or I, it isn't that clear. The OP may want to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
void func1(const int* value, int change)
{
  int* valueToUse;

  if(change)
  {
    (*(int*)value)++;
    valueToUse = (int*)value;
  }
  else
  {
     valueToUse = (int*)value;  // <= here the Error occurs
  }

  func2(valueToUse);
}
```

But you don't really need this `valueToUse`, it's what i think, so.

```
void func1(const int* value, int change)
{
  if(change)
    (*(int*)value)++;

  func2(value);
}
```

Comment: The `(int*)` shuts up the compiler, but does not solve the problem properly. Why not just change the argument type?

Answer (score 0):

```
const int* value
```

This means pointer to a constant int `value`. It is not permitted to change the value of a constant int.
There are two ways of solving this.

1. Change signature of first function `void func1(int* value, bool change)`
2. Pass arguments to func1 after constant casting using `const_cast` and change
   `int changedValue = (*value)++;` to  `int changedValue = *value + 1;`

Comment: There is a third case where what value points to actually isn't expected to change.

Comment: @stefaanv I was not trying to solve the logical statements of the OP. Just letting him know about the two ways his syntatical errors can be resolved.

Answer (score -6):

Well, running this code i receive just a warning, though i think that type conversion will help you.

```
valueToUse = (int*)value;
```

Comment: This just puts duct tape over the compiler's mouth. It screams the code is wrong, but you choose to shut it up?